# REST method that does to GET what PATCH does to PUT

Tags: rest, http

`PATCH` allows to update only some fields of a resource, resulting in a partial update, while `PUT` updates the complete resource. `GET` only ever gets the complete resource.

Is there a `RESTful` convention for partially querying a resource, if said resource is quite heavy and contains lots of fields?

May be a convention regarding the query in the URL? Or the definition of another pseudo-resource?

Comment: Typically you pass params in this instance I believe `GET /resource?year=2014...`

Comment: @C.B.: that would be for filtering the matching resources. I am wondering how to limit the content of the matching resources. For example, only get the `FirstName` field of the `user` resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any other method that is specifically for getting only a portion of a resource. In my experience there are two simple options. (My *opinion* is that the second option is nicer, but there might be disagreement there.)

## Option 1

Use a query parameter to allow selecting which properties you want returned.

```
GET /basket/17

{
  "blueberry": 5,
  "grape": 7,
  "watermelon": "<base64 encoded file>"
}

GET /basket/17?p=blueberry&p=grape

{
  "blueberry": 5,
  "grape": 7
}
```

## Option 2

All heavy properties of a resource become separate resources, and the main resource has links to them.

```
GET /basket/17

{
  "blueberry": 5,
  "grape": 7,
  "watermelon": "/basket/watermelon/17"
}

GET /basket/watermelon/17

<bytes of file>
```

Comment: this are also the 2 main options I was considering. (a third being creating another resource that mirrors some of the properties, for instance a `GET /halfbasket/17` that would return `{"grape": 7}`)

Comment: @njzk2 I actually would avoid that third option. Having more than one way to get at some data via your API is not good (excepting query/search functionality). "Option 1" above comes close to violating this advise, but it technically doesn't because you are essentially querying the resource `/basket/17` by appending a query string.

Comment: good point, it can indeed be confusing (at best), not to mention potential conflicts for other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom range unit to express your semantics and use GET. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7233.html.

Comment: and we'll revisit the problem of how to gzip it :D

Comment: an interesting idea. I fear it may not be very clear, though.